# $_POST unset and reset with parse_str data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to perform a quick AJAX preview of a page that redefines the Super Global `$_POST` variable with that from `parse_str` (serialized form data).  Basically, am wanting to do this quickly, and have succeeded in doing this on localhost, but seems to fail on the actual live server.  Not sure if this is due to wordpress multisite or not...

But basically, I'm serializing the form in AJAX (this is the same form that gets sent via $_POST).  Than I do `parse_str($formData, $_POST);` in the php function where $data is the serialized form data from the AJAX request.

I have put `global $_POST;` at the top of the AJAX php function for overwriting it.  Here's my php ajax function code that works fine on localhost:

```
function hunter_preview_quote()
{
    global $_POST;

    check_ajax_referer('preview-quote', 'security');

    $response = array(
        'error' => 'Error Occurred while attempting to generate a preview for this quote. Please try again.'
    );

    if (!current_user_can('manage_options'))
    {
        $response['error'] = 'You do not have permission to view this.';
        echo json_encode($response);
        die();
    }

    $formData = $_POST['form'];
    unset($_POST);

    // Rewrite the Global $_POST data send with the form, with that from the serialized form array!
    parse_str($formData, $_POST);

    ob_start();
    hunter_admin_build_form_html(false);
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    if (!empty($content))
        $response['content'] = $content;

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

It is calling `hunter_admin_build_form_html` which is responsible for taking the $_POST data from the form and building a preview.  The param false tells it not to send an email.

Anyways, this does not work on the live site, and I'm not sure if it has something to do with Wordpress Multisite being installed on that site or not.  What is supposed to happen with the returned response here is as follows:

```
function OpenPopupWindow(content, title, w, h, opts) {
   var _innerOpts = '';
   if(opts !== null && typeof opts === 'object' ){
       for (var p in opts ) {
           if (opts.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
               _innerOpts += p + '=' + opts[p] + ',';
           }
       }
   }
     // Fixes dual-screen position, Most browsers, Firefox
   var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
   var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

   var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
   var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

   var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
   var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
   var w = window.open('', title, _innerOpts + ' width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

   $(w.document.body).html('<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>' + title + '</title></head>' + content + '</html>');

    // Puts focus on the newWindow
   if (window.focus) {
       w.focus();
   }

   return w;
}

$("#submit-preview-quote").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
        $formData = $this.closest('form').serialize();

    var data = {
        action: 'hunter_preview_quote',
        security: HUNTER_CONTACTFORM_admin['preview_quote_nonce'],
        form: $formData
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: HUNTER_CONTACTFORM_admin.ajax_url,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response) {

        // Load the Preview popup now... if all is fine!
        if (response.hasOwnProperty('content'))
            var w = OpenPopupWindow(response['content'], 'Quote Preview', '700', '500', {toolbar: 'no', location: 'no', status: 'no', menubar: 'no', scrollbars: 'yes', resizable: 'yes'} );
        else if (response.hasOwnProperty('error'))
            alert(response['error']);

    }).fail(function(response) {

        if (response.hasOwnProperty('error'))
            alert(response['error']);

    }).always(function(response) {
        // Nothing needed in here...
    });

});
```

So, it should open up the preview in a new window, but instead, I am getting crazy javascript values in an alert box like so:

```
function (){return f&&(c&&!b&&(h=f.length-1,g.push(c)),function d(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){n.isFunction(c)?a.unique&&j.has(c)||f.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==n.type(c)&&d(c)})}(arguments),c&&!b&&i()),this}
```

Not sure what is causing this to happen, but it would seem that there is an error somewhere, but why is it pushing out a js function?  More digging into this has confirmed that the AJAX is actually failing somehow.  So it is hitting the .fail part of the ajax.

Turns out it was due to NewRelic pushing js that was not properly json encoded, and so it needed to be disabled!

Comment: I don't know if I would necessarily mess with the `$_POST` like that. Are you just trying to pass global/out-of-scope data is all?

Comment: Also, can you track that alert in your console? Maybe if you know where it's coming from you can figure out easier what to do. That is a strange anonymous function though. Or, if you have access to all the files, just do a search for that string, it should show you where that is coming from.

Comment: I'm trying to use ajax to use the same $_POST variables to generate a preview from the form, using the same function that also generates an email, so that I can show the client a preview of the email before it gets sent.

Comment: How to track an alert in the console?

Comment: Depending on your browser, you can set markers in the script to sort of track where things are happening. I would first try searching for a part of that function string like `a.unique&&j.has(c)` in your files and see if it pops up anywhere in a script. Sometimes just doing a search in your directory will find where that is being generated, then you can backtrack it a bit...sometimes...depends on the complexity.

Comment: Posted up the XHR response from the ajax call.  Looks like it is generating the preview html, but is inserting <script> above it... weird.

Comment: That looks like it's returning all the HTML via `json_encode()`

Comment: So why is it not loading up in the popup window?  Why is it failing via ajax?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, lit looks like it's doing the top portion as normal js and then the rest is the encoded html...strange.

Comment: On my localhost, none of that `script` gets outputted, just on the live site.  Wonder where to look to see where that's happening at though.  I don't see that code in the header.php file anywhere... and why would it be inserted especially since I'm doing an `ob_start` and clean here.  My localhost starts with the response being the `<body>`

Comment: Do you use something from `newrelic.com`? There is a link in that portion referring to them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was an issue with New Relic.  In the ajax function, just did this and it removed the script stuff for newrelic:

```
if (extension_loaded ('newrelic')) {
    newrelic_disable_autorum();
}
```

Thanks for your help with this Rasclatt!